# KML When I click in a Placemark display lines to other coordinates

Tags: kml

I have some `<placemark>` and I dont know if it is posible

1. When I select a placemark I want to appear lines to diferents points (that I
   know the cordinates)

**From my Placemark to diferente points**

I dont have any idea how I can do it. I was trying to put all the code inside `<description>` but that doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found something helps me :D

http://www.barnabu.co.uk/uk-and-ireland-flight-maps/

They are ussing like a rollover in the placemark not showing the lines in one state